# How do I reference a row in information_schema.tables in a MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, information-schema

In MySQL the information_schema.tables.table_name column identifies the names of all tables within the database.  I want to record the name of the table in a generic update history table.  I could do it with a varchar(64) but that's potentially quite wasteful if table names are long.  I could use a lookup table to store a copy of the name, then have a foreign key pointing to my_table_names.id, but that seems like more work than necessary given that a table of table names already exists.  The problem is that I can't see any sort of "id" column or other primary key when I look with phpMyAdmin.  So how do I refer to a row?

Comment: Keep in mind `information_schema.tables.table_name` will not contain unique entries, since a table is identified by `schema.table_name`

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. The combination `TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TABLE_NAME` will always be unique.

Comment: Ooh what about the checksum field. I don't have MySQL handy to checkout  whats there but could be useful for this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: Sorry, don't understand what you mean by `schema.table_name`, but surely the combination `table_schema,table_name` will be unique, otherwise you could have two tables with the same name.  That means there has to be a single row in `information_schema.tables`, but what is the "index" of that row?

Comment: Yea, I was just mentioning that `table_name` by itself is not unique. Because in your question you only refer to `table_name` as the field you want to key to. Let me just answer you question. "So how do I refer to a row?" For any well designed table you refer to any row by a unique key of the table. Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to find out what a possible UK is. A table needn't have a single column that identifies it.

Comment: `show create table information_schema.tables;` shows that the table has no primary key - or any other keys or indexing for that matter! - just columns.  It also says `ENGINE=MEMORY` so there's probably some automatic hash or B-tree indexing going on.  So I guess the answer to my question is that you can't use `information_schema.tables` as a de-duplication lookup table as there isn't an "index" that's shorter than the table name itself.